# scp alias to remove colons/special characters

Tags: scp, special-characters

Recently Windows 10 added a bash shell as part of their Linux Subsystems for Windows initiative. This is generally fantastic, but I've run into an interesting problem: Windows filesystems do not allow colons/other special characters in their file names. Therefore, when I try to `scp` something like this:

```
scp user@remote:/path/to/file-2016-09-07_08:45:45.txt .
```

scp throws an invalid argument error. One way around this is to specify a new file name without special characters, but this is cumbersome when trying to do something like

```
scp user@remote:/path/to/file-2016-09-07* .
```

because all of the files throw the invalid argument error. Is there some code I could place in my .bashrc file that would take any scp argument and replace each offending character with `_`, for example? The equivalent to

```
 scp user@remote:/path/to/file-2016-09-07_08:45:45 file-2016-09-07_08_45_45.txt
```

but portable for use with `*`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a parameter substitution on the name — if you had it in a variable.  But the shell does not "see" the wildcard expansion on the remote filesystem which `scp` may "see", so a shell alias would not work.

From the description, you could write a script which does what you are asking for, e.g.,

- use `ssh` to obtain a list of the remote filenames, and
- in a loop...
- form a local filename, and
- use scp to copy the actual remote/local files.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using alternative Unicode characters in your original file names, allowing copies without any naming problems.

- For colon, use [꞉ - Modifier Letter Colon: U+A789 - Unicode Character Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/A789/).
- For question mark, use [？ - Fullwidth Question Mark: U+FF1F - Unicode Character Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/FF1F/).
- For asterisk, use [⁎ - Low Asterisk: U+204E - Unicode Character Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/204E/).

Comment: Can you explain how the OP could use this information to rewrite the target filenames?

Comment: @roaima, what I'm suggesting means never having to rewrite the target filenames.  In the original source, use the Unicode visually equivalent character right from the very beginning.  Then the filenames will always automatically work everywhere without one's having to worry about what the rules are.